# error while using deleteOne in app.delete function in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose-deleteone

** trying to use the app.delete  and trying to delete document from mondo db using delete one...it keep throwing errror. how to solve this error ? **
```  require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5001
const connectDB = require('./config/db')
const errorHandler = require('./middleware/error')
const Product =require('./models/product')
const cors = require('cors')

````
    // Connect DB
    connectDB()
    
    
    // Middleware
    app.use(cors())
    app.use(express.json())
    app.use('/auth', require('./routes/authRoutes'))
    app.use('/admin', require('./routes/adminRoutes'))
    app.use('/customer', require('./routes/customerRoutes'))
    app.use('/staff', require('./routes/staffMemberRoutes'))
    // error handler - should be *last* piece of middleware
    app.use(errorHandler)
    
    
    app.get('/all-products', (req, res) => {
      Product.find({}, (error, posts) => {
        if(error) {
          res.json({error: 'Unable to fetch products!'}) 
        } else {
          res.json(posts)
        }
      })
    })
    
    
    
    app.post ('/add-products',(req,res) =>{
      console.log("add-products has been fired")
      const imageurl = req.body.imageurl 
      const title = req.body.title
      const description = req.body.description 
      const rate = req.body.rate 
      const category = req.body.category 
      const subcategory = req.body.subcategory 
    
      let product  = new Product({
        imageurl: imageurl,
        title: title,
        description: description,
        rate: rate,
        category: category,
        subcategory: subcategory,
      })
    
    
      product.save((error) => {
        if(error) {
          res.json({error: 'Unable to save the product!'})
        } else {
          res.json({success: true, message: 'New product Saved'})
        }
      })
    
    })
    
    
    
    app.delete('/product/:productId', (req, res) => {
    
      const productId = req.params.productId 
    
      Product.deleteOne({
        _id: productId
      }, (error, result) => {
        if(error) {
          res.json({error: 'Unable to delete product'})
        } else {
          res.json({success: true, message: 'Product deleted successfully!'})
        }
      })
    
    })
    
    
    
    app.put('/update-product/:productId', (req, res) => {
    
      const productId = req.params.productId 
      const imageurl = req.body.imageurl 
      const title = req.body.title
      const description = req.body.description 
      const rate = req.body.rate 
      const category = req.body.category 
      const subcategory = req.body.subcategory 
    
      const updatedProduct = {
        imageurl: imageurl,
        title: title,
        description: description,
        rate: rate,
        category: category,
        subcategory: subcategory,
      }
    
      Product.findByIdAndUpdate(productId, updatedProduct, (error, result) => {
          if(error) {
              res.json({error: 'Unable to updated the Product'})
          } else {
              res.json({success: true, message: 'Product updated successfully!'})
          }
      })
    
    })
    
    
    const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`)
    })
    
    // makes giant server errors concise and simple to read
    process.on('unhandledRejection', (err, promise) => {
      console.log(`Logged Error: ${err}`)
      server.close(() => process.exit(1))
    })```
````

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(error) {
      res.json({error: 'Unable to delete product'})
    }
```

In this line, replace res.json with:

```
res.json({error})
```

And then comment here the output (error message on the console)